# Losing data when joining two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not even sure how exactly to ask this question so bear with me.

I have two tables, meets and locations, they are linked by the meet's 'loc' and the location's 'id'

I'm using this query:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM meets LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.id=meets.loc ORDER BY date DESC";
$meets = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

though it joins the table successfully I lose the meet's 'id' because it's being overwritten by the location's 'id'.  So I end up with two identical entries 'id' and 'loc'.

Is there any way to avoid this because I need to call on the meet id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do not select *, select the columns you need and rename them using the `as` key word like so

```
SELECT locations.id as loc_id, meets.id as meets_id, ... FROM meets LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.id=meets.loc ORDER BY date DESC
```

replacing `...` with other columns you would like to select and possible renames of them.

Comment: I was actually thinking that was the case, unfortunate because I need to select a lot of columns so it's going to be a long query.

Comment: @Muskogeee `SELECT *` is almost always incorrect in a production setting. It's fine for ad hoc queries in a query analyzer, but it shouldn't be used anyplace a query is used programmatically. Here you're not only forcing MySQL to look up the table column names, you're asking it to return *all* the data in those tables to you. If someone comes along later and adds, say, a binary picture field to the table, your query would return the image data to PHP in the result set even if you didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could alias the locations.id with a query like:

```
SELECT meets.*, locations.id AS loc_id FROM meets LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.id=meets.loc ORDER BY date DESC
```

You could add any other columns from `locations` that you might also need.  You could further only select explicit columns from `meet` rather than `meet.*`

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use `SELECT meets.*, locations.id as locationId, locations.<row> as location<Row>, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the syntax is exactly the same, but in SQL Server the syntax would be:

```
SELECT m.*, l.id as LocationId 
FROM meets m
LEFT JOIN locations l
ON l.id=m.loc 
ORDER BY date DESC
```